# Thin words without scaling

Tags: modeling

I have a multiple part piece it is a word that fits inside an outline of that word .  The problem is the letters are too tight to fit inside the outline.  If I scale it then it doesn't fit, i just want to reduce the outside of the letters without scaling it.  ie removing the tiniest percentage from the outline of the letter.  How can I do this?  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try the `Offset Edges` tool from the "Edit Mesh Tools" addon that comes with Blender, you just need to activate it. It will make crossing geo so there will be some clean up

Comment: You might try making the text regular size, then using the bevel option in the font datablock to fatten the outline.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "shrink", and Blender has the exact tool - "Shrink/Fatten" (Alt+S).
[image: shrink]

Note that this won't work on flat text, as it moves verts along the normals. For the same reason, make sure to only select the sides to avoid deforming it in the wrong direction.
Hold Alt or tick "Offset Even" above the viewport to ensure consistent thickness.